# Fedora Offline-Upgrade shutdown instead of reboot from CLI

Tags: command-line, fedora, systemd, dnf, software-updates

Before turning off my Laptop (which runs Fedora 36) I like to run `sudo dnf offline-upgrade download -y && sudo dnf offline-upgrade reboot || sudo shutdown now` So that all pending updates get installed automatically and I don't have to worry about using the Software Center or shutting down via GNOME.
The only problem is by running `sudo dnf offline-upgrade reboot` my Laptop reboots as the command states and I would like it to shutdown and install the rest of the updates the next time I start my Laptop.

Is there a way (maybe using systemd) to shutdown into the upgrade process via Command Line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update (2023-04-08) - this is available as of [dnf-plugins-core 4.4.0](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf-plugins-core/releases/tag/4.4.0):*

```bash
dnf offline-upgrade reboot --poweroff
```

---

It looks like it's hard-coded — see [plugins/system_upgrade.py](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf-plugins-extras/blob/master/plugins/system_upgrade.py#L689):

```py
    def transaction_upgrade(self):
        Plymouth.message(_("Upgrade complete! Cleaning up and rebooting..."))
        self.log_status(_("Upgrade complete! Cleaning up and rebooting..."),
                        UPGRADE_FINISHED_ID)
        self.run_clean()
        if self.opts.tid[0] == "upgrade":
            reboot()
```

And `reboot()` is this:

```py
    def transaction_upgrade(self):
        Plymouth.message(_("Upgrade complete! Cleaning up and rebooting..."))
        self.log_status(_("Upgrade complete! Cleaning up and rebooting..."),
                        UPGRADE_FINISHED_ID)
        self.run_clean()
        if self.opts.tid[0] == "upgrade":
            reboot()
```

... but that variable is only for testing, and really meant to prevent the *initial* reboot.

What you want seems like a very reasonable enhancement -- maybe a `--poweroff-after` flag or something to change that `systemctl reboot` call to `systemctl poweroff`.